# How to convert view to Bitmap with shadow in Android L

Tags: android, bitmap, android-view

I want to convert a `ScrollView` to Bitmap and I found the solution below.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
    // store the origin state
    int originWidth = v.getMeasuredWidth();
    int originHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    // capture the view
    int specWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(originWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int specHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    v.measure(specWidth, specHeight);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.default_background));
    v.draw(c);

    // restore the view
    v.measure(originWidth, originHeight);
    v.layout(0, 0, originWidth, originHeight);
    return b;
}
```

It works fine except the shadow, as there are `CardView` in the layout, the method loses all the shadows, it makes the image a little strange.

So are there any ways to convert without losing shadows?

Comment: I use the `getDrawingCache()` method and I think shadows are preserved. You might try it instead. Something like: `v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap myScreenshot = v.getDrawingCache();`

Comment: But this method seems only get the view visible, I want to capture the whole view, it this possible?